# Exportar formulário HTML para PDF com campo input inicializado por js não aparece no documento Pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jspdf

Eu tenho um formulário HTML onde cada tag input está com o seu atributo value vazio. Este atributo value deve ser preenchido de forma aleatória por um código javascript. Até aí está tudo OK. O problema é que quando eu uso o plugin (jspdf) para submeter este formulário a uma saída em pdf, o campo value do formulário não aparece na saída do documento pdf. Com isso o documento é exportado apenas com o label, sem o seu conteúdo.

O nome sorteado aparece na tela mas infelizmente não é setado na propriedade value da tag input e por conta disso não aparece no documento pdf quando é exportado.

Minha dúvida, existe alguma forma de eu forçar o preenchimento da propriedade value da tag input pelo código javascript?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conforme se pode ver no print teve o nome gerado "Monge", mas ao inspecionar o elemento o seu atributo value está vazio. Quando eu mando fazer o download via pdf o documento fica conforme abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Utilizando jsPDF- http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/#

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');

pdf.addHTML(document.body,function() {
    //Funcionou !
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Para gerar PDF a melhor ferramenta é o jsPDF. Com ele pode imprimir a secção do seu HTML que quiser. Existem vários plugins disoniveis entre eles o jsPDF & autoTable que permite imprimir uma tabela completa ou o jspdf & html2canvas que permite tirar uma foto de uma pagina ou secção para imprimir.

Neste caso aconçelho o uso do jspdf & html2canvas.

```js
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

$('#cmd').click(function () {   
    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
    <h3>Filter Section</h3>
    <p>Test will be print where</p>
</div>
<div id="editor"></div>
<button id="cmd">Generate PDF</button>
```

Pode ver também aqui https://fiddle.jshell.net/user/sereno/fiddles/ varios exemplos.